# Why is a member function with a pointer parameter requiring a pointer to a pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a generic class:

```
template<typename T>
class QuadTree {
```

The class has member variables for its nodes like this

```
QuadTree<T*>* nw;
```

The problem that I have is with following member function:

```
bool insert(T *obj) {
        //...
        if (nw->insert(obj)) return true;
        //...
```

I thought this would work, but I get an error unless I pass &obj, a pointer to a pointer. When I set `T` to be `Circle` in Visual Studio, Intellisense shows the method signature as `bool QuadTree<Circle *>::insert(Circle **obj)`, but why is it that way?

Edit: Here is a stripped version of the class:

```
template<typename T>
class QuadTree {
    const int QT_NODE_CAPACITY = 4;
    std::vector<T*> elements;
    QuadTree<T*>* nw;
    QuadTree<T*>* ne;
    QuadTree<T*>* sw;
    QuadTree<T*>* se;

public:
    QuadTree<T>() : nw(nullptr), ne(nullptr), sw(nullptr), se(nullptr) {
        elements = std::vector<T*>();
    }


    bool insert(T* obj) {
        //if (!boundary.containsObject(obj)) {
        //    return false; //Object does not belong here
        //}
        if (elements.size() < QT_NODE_CAPACITY && nw == nullptr) {
            elements.push_back(obj);
            return true;
        }
        if (nw == nullptr) {
            //subdivide();
        }
        //Try to insert element in one of the subtrees until it succeeds
        if (nw->insert(&obj)) return true;
        if (ne->insert(&obj)) return true;
        if (sw->insert(&obj)) return true;
        if (se->insert(&obj)) return true;

        return false; //should never be reached
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not bits of fragmented code.

Comment: Your description is a little hard to follow.  Please post a [mre].

Comment: Why `QuadTree<T*> *nw`? Why not `QuadTree<T> *nw;`? Though, this might be answerable with a bit more code. (How about a [mcve]?)

Comment: Probably because your function inside the class is `QuadTree<T>::Insert(T *obj)`, but then you instantiate `QuadTree<T*>`.

Comment: A `QuadTree<T>` having nodes of type `QuadTree<T*>` sounds like an odd choice, and is probably the root of your problems.

Comment: Re-calling that a quad tree is just another kind of tree, with `QuadTree<T*> *nw;`, for the root with an element of type `T`, the first level children would have element type `T*`, the second element type `T**` and so on. Feels wrong somehow...

Comment: To be more explicit, your `QuadTree<Circle>` has nodes of type `QuadTree<Circle*>`. Those trees have nodes of type `QuadTree<Circle**>`, and the nodes of those have type `QuadTree<Circle***>`, an so on.

Comment: within context of instantiated  class `QuadTree<T*>`  class T would be be a pointer to T of outside context. You have to define some trait class that would fixate the original T, perhaps you would need  to use CRTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class template...

```
template<typename T>
class QuadTree {}
```

... if T is a pointer during instantiation (which it is)...

```
QuadTree<T*>* nw; //NOTE <T*>, not <T>
```

... this implies that `bool insert(T* obj)` , when instantiated, becomes bool `insert((T*)* obj)` (as T was already type pointer - *brackets for emphasis*). Therefore it is not necessary to take address of object when inserting (amongst many other mistakes). When you do take the address of the object, you are really taking the address of a temporary (variable to the pointer) - that is your mistake.

A solution is perhaps to change insert to `insert(T& obj)`, which would allow you to take the address of the reference, or to `insert(T*& obj)`, which would mean you've stored the address of the real pointer (and not the address of the argument that was passed by value... a variable having the value of the address who's lifetime is scoped **only** to the function)... hope it makes sense).